# stop instantiating prefab if hit limit but continue if prefabs get destroyed

Tags: unity-game-engine, spawn

i have a wave system set up and it instantiates a specific amount of enemy prefabs, however say there are supposed to be 100 enemies in total that have to be instantiated on said wave, thats a lot for the player to handle so i want to set a limit (doing it like in COD: Zombies) for how many prefabs are allowed to be active at a time.

```
    IEnumerator SpawnWave (Wave _wave)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < _wave.count; i++)
        {
            if (curZombiesSpawned < maxZombiesSpawned)
            {
                SpawnEnemy();
                Debug.Log("spawnenemy");
            }
            yield return new WaitForSeconds( 1f/_wave.rate );
        }

        state = SpawnState.WAITING;
        yield break;
    }

    void SpawnEnemy()
    {
        Transform _sp = spawnPoints[Random.Range(0, spawnPoints.Length)];
        PhotonNetwork.InstantiateRoomObject (enemyObject.name, _sp.position, _sp.rotation);
        curZombiesSpawned++;
    }
```

before i instantiate the enemy i want to check if the currently spawned enemies is less than the max amount of enemies spawned at a time.

but lets say on x wave there are supposed to be 50 enemies, but the limit is 24, i only want 24 to spawn, and when i kill x amount of enemies, i want to spawn more enemies till it reaches the limit again. doing that until all 50 are dead, then the next wave starts again

current problem: if the enemy amount on x wave is greater than the limit, it spawns x amount of enemies (spawn the amount of what the limit is set to) but when i kill some (thus destroy the object) they dont keep spawning again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
    IEnumerator SpawnWave (Wave _wave)
    {
        int spawnedEnemiesCount = 0;
        while(spawnedEnemiesCount < _wave.count)
        {
            while (curZombiesSpawned < maxZombiesSpawned && spawnedEnemiesCount < _wave.count)
            {
                SpawnEnemy();
                spawnedEnemiesCount++;
                Debug.Log("spawnenemy");
            }
            yield return new WaitForSeconds( 1f/_wave.rate );
        }
    }
```

Comment: it successfully respawns the enemies exactly how i wanted them to, thats a huge step in the right direction but there is 1 major problem, they all spawn at once, not really fast but just all at once..

Comment: if you want to spawn a maximum of one enemy at a time, not all, replace the second `while` (right before `SpawnEnemy()` call) with the `if` statement. if you need a spawn period less than your `1f / _wave.rate` - you can add another `yield return` inside the second `while` block.

Comment: that fixes everything!! thank you so much, everything works exactly how i wanted!